# Large width Integers in Julia?

Tags: types, numbers, julia

Julia's Integer data types are defined in julia itself as bitstype, so can i define something like a Int256 and make julia work with Integer  literals that are bigger than Int128 and use them as Int256?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BigInt` for arbitrary-sized ints, but it gives a performance penalty. You can definitely speed it up if you used a fixed-size larger Int and defined fast rules, either via lookup-tables or something like [DoubleDouble.jl](https://github.com/simonbyrne/DoubleDouble.jl) for ints. You can use this by defining BitsTypes [as its gone over in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK3zRXhrFZY) and define the appropriate operations on BitsTypes.

To make it fast you would want to try and use the operations built into the processor for integers to get more speed, and then somehow compensate for your extra size (this is what DoubleDouble.jl does it). You could always just define the operations bit by bit, but that most likely will not be as fast as plugging into the existing integer adding circuits on the processor. There is some mathematical/algorithmic work that would have to be done to make this work out correctly.

In theory (and judging by examples with floats: DoubleDouble, ArbFloats, ArbReals, various Unums, etc.), you can do all of this in Julia and release this as a packge. I just don't know of anyone who has done it already.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is the `BigInt` type which can be of arbitrary size.  You can read about that in the docs [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#man-arbitrary-precision-arithmetic).  I've found though that if you're doing much heavy computation with it, there will be a big performance penalty.

Apart from this you can certainly define your own type.  I think that one of the challenges is that not all of the under-the-hood libraries in other languages like C that Julia works with support integers this big.  I found, for instance, the following [discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/757) on Julia's GitHub informative when I was looking into issues of the `BigFloat` type.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this question as asked: it is not possible without hacking at Julia itself. To be precise, the parser knows only about the built-in integer types. The `Int128` support for literals is actually hardcoded in the parser:

```
(if (and (integer? n) (> n 9223372036854775807))
    `(macrocall @int128_str ,s)
    n)
```

So what you want with literals is not possible without changing the language itself. OK, so let's say we give up on literal support. Could we at least make a `Int256` type and get it to work well? Of course, but it is not as easy as you might think.

The reason it is so tricky: internally, base Julia has `BitInteger`, `BitUnsigned`, and `BitSigned` types that implement most of the integer functionality. However, these types cannot be extended, because they are unions instead of abstract types. For example, we can see where and how `&` is implemented:

```
julia> @which 0x1 & 0x2
&{T<:Union{Int128,Int16,Int32,Int64,Int8,UInt128,UInt16,UInt32,UInt64,UInt8}}(x::T, y::T) at int.jl:141
```

As you can see, the implementation of `&` is for a specific set of types, and this set of types is not extensible. This is the case for a huge chunk of primitive functions on integers. Thus, we would have to reimplement much of that functionality, which is quite a bit of work! It is possible of course, but nobody wants to do that. On the other hand, if we had simply implemented `Int256` support within `Base` itself, adding it to the appropriate unions, it would be much easier. But it is unlikely this will be added to `Base`, as in many applications, an arbitrary sized integer like `BigInt` will be more useful than a fixed but large integer like `Int256`.

In fact, there is an example of how complex reimplementing all integer behaviour is: `BigInt`. But wait, `BigInt` is in `Base`, right? While technically true, `BigInt` is actually defined in a well-isolated module named `Base.GMP`. We can see that it is not a member of any of the unions defined in base for the fixed-width integers. So we can actually follow the format of how `BigInt` is implemented to implement a new integer type. But I will leave it up to you whether you consider it [worthwhile](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/gmp.jl), as the implementation of `BigInt` is itself a large amount of code.

Comment: Even though the parser hardcodes a call to the macro, you can simply replace the macro definition (and that of big_str, for integer literals that don't fit in 128 bits).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Probably the easiest way to do so, would be to make your own wrapper for the GMP library, using BigInt as a starting point (I've actually been working on a better, faster, and thread-safe wrapper for MPFR, to replace BigFloat, adding bigger fixed size floating point types and a mutable big float "container" type as well).
You can also overwrite the definitions for the macros int128_str, uint128_str, and big_str, to handle the conversions of literals, so that won't even be a problem (except for the annoying warning when the package is loaded about replacing Base.@int128_str etc.